# How can I input boolean values from Gherkin datatable in golang?

Tags: go, bdd, gherkin

I have an input Gherkin DataTable where in one column I have boolean values, when I am reading the DataTable the boolean values are converted into strings. My final goal is to send the data read from DataTable in json format as a body of an API. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As I was looking for an answer, I found out that assist dog does not have implementation for boolean parsers. So in order to implement this I wrote a boolean parser that simply converts the incoming string to boolean and registered the parser under the default parsers in the assistDog.go file.
I am writing this answer so as to help others or as for a future reference.